# glm::translate outputs transposed matrix

Tags: opengl, opengl-3, glm-math

When I'm trying to do some translations in OpengGL 3.3+ with glm, glm returns transposed matrices. Some example:

```
glm::mat4 matrix;
std::cout<<glm::to_string(matrix)<<std::endl; //output correct identity matrix
glm::translate(matrix,glm::vec3(0.0,3.3,0.0));
std::cout<<glm::to_string(matrix)<<std::endl;
```

Output:

```
mat4x4((1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000),
       (0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000),
       (0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000), 
       (0.000000, 3.300000, 0.000000, 1.000000))
```

When i pass it to the shader i've got disturbed image...

So, I'dont know what I'm doing wrong... Is that normal?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5097291/incorrect-order-of-matrix-values-in-glm?rq=1

Comment: Thanks, I should use:  glUniformMatrix4fv(matrix_location,1,GL_FALSE,glm::value_ptr(matrix));

Comment: There is no problem with `glm::translate()`.

`glm::translate()` returns a correct matrix since its matrices are column-major!

For prints/debugging use this:
`std::cout<<glm::to_string(glm::transpose(matrix))<<std::endl;`